# Can we generate value for a property as a combination of other properties while deserializing a JSON in c#?

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

I have an Artifact class for deserializing a JSON which is handled using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject()`.

The problem am trying to resolve is that I need to set the value of a property in the model, which is not part of the JSON, as a combination of two other properties that are present in the JSON.

```
public class Artefact : RealmObject
    {
        [PrimaryKey]
        public string Key { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "instructors")]
        public IList<Instructors> Instructors { get; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "startAt")]
        public string StartAt { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "endAt")]
        public string EndAt { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "actualStartAt")]
        public string ActualStartAt { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "actualEndAt")]
        public string ActualEndAt { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "status")]
        public string APIStatus { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "assignmentNumber")]
        public int AssignmentNumber { get; set; } = -1;
    }

List<Artefact> artefacts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Artefact>>(data, _settings);
```

While deserializing the 'data' which is a JSON string obtained as an API response, I want the value of `Key` to be set as `ProductId.ToString() + AssignmentNumber.ToString()`

Comment: Is it always going to be `ProductId.ToString() + AssignmentNumber.ToString()`, or just when deserializing from json? Also, if productId is 1 and AssignmentNumber is 5, the result of this expression is a string containing 15. Is that what you really want?

Comment: Well, one problem here is that `Key` is an `int`, but you're trying to set it to a string. Ignoring that, is there a reason you can't just use `foreach (var artefact in artefacts) { artefact.Key = artefact.ProductId.ToString() + artefact.AssignmentNumber.ToString();}`? Not elegant perhaps, but gets the job done.

Comment: @ZoharPeled yes that's what I want. For us the combination of assignment number and product id is always unique whereas individually they are not.

Comment: What about ProductId 1 and Assignment 11 vs ProductId 11 and Assignment 1?

Comment: @stuartd yeah that will do the job. But like you pointed out was looking for something elegant.

Comment: @stuartd hey thanks, thats a valid point. in that case i will make Key as string and the value as "id"+ProductId.ToString() + "assignment" +AssignmentNumber.ToString()

Answer (score 0):

You can add a property in your class like this:

```
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string MyProp { get { return this.ProductId.ToString() + this.AssignmentNumber.ToString(); } }
```